Is it possible to force bash `read` to consistently read the requested number of Unicode characters?
Consider the following script, which attempts to read a fixed number of characters from a file containing Unicode using bash's read function, and then counts how many characters are read.
MWE.sh
#!/bin/bash

char_count=$1

while true; do
  read -r -n $char_count output
  echo -n "$output" | wc -m
  exit
done < MWE.txt

MWE.txt
main · square

Suppose I invoke it like this:
for x in $(seq 1 10 ); do ./MWE.sh $x; done

This produces the following output:
1
2
3
4
4
6
6
8
9
10

If bash is attempting to read a particular number of characters, then I would expect a consistently increasing character count.
However, we observe a discontinuity in character count.
For example, when we attempt to read 5 characters, we obtain only 4 characters.
Why does this happen, and is there a way to make read -n <count> consistently read the requested number of Unicode characters, rather than sometimes reading fewer when more are available?
I am running the following bash version:
bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)


Have a look at Length of string in bash, then try to prepand wc by LC_ALL=C: this: echo -n "$output" | LC_ALL=C wc -c!

I've edited the question to remove reference to byte counts -- this question is not a duplicate since it's not about byte counts vs character counts.
It is focused on the behavior of read when IFS is not set.

Then you have to prepend read command by LANG=C or LC_ALL=C.  Try: LC_ALL=C IFS= read -r -n $count variable <input...  All sample are on posted answer. Try samples I've posted as comments on your self answer.

And yes, it's still a duplicarte, as your issue stand in difference between characters and bytes counts.

The issue was that I didn't specify IFS.

I'm trying to read characters rather than bytes, so I do not actually care about the byte count.

help read says:

Reads a single line from the standard input, or from file descriptor
FD if the -u option is supplied.  The line is split into fields as
with word splitting, and the first word is assigned to the first NAME,
the second word to the second NAME, and so on, with any leftover words
assigned to the last NAME.

When you read 5 characters (-n 5), the last character was the space character.  At that space character bash split your input into words, assigning "the first" of them to the variable output, which gets the value "main" which has 4 characters.
When you read more than 5 characters, bash did not split your input into words because there was only one variable, and your input was assigned to it literally.  Had you given read multiple variable names to assign to, the splitting would have occurred.

If you want to read bytes instead of chars, use read prefixed by LANG=C:
LANG=C read -r -n $char_count output

read (and only read command) will work with char === byte

It appears that bash is skipping over characters that are in the default IFS value, such as space.
I get correct character counts when I set IFS to nothing.
#!/bin/bash

char_count=$1

while true; do
  IFS= read -r -n $char_count output
  echo -n "$output" | wc -m
  exit
done < MWE.txt

Output:
for x in $(seq 1 10 ); do ./MWE.sh $x; done
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

It appears that using -N instead of -n also results in the desired behavior, which is hinted at but not explicitly stated by help read.
      -n nchars return after reading NCHARS characters rather than waiting
                for a newline, but honor a delimiter if fewer than
                NCHARS characters are read before the delimiter
      -N nchars return only after reading exactly NCHARS characters, unless
                EOF is encountered or read times out, ignoring any
                delimiter


Try this: for i in {5..9};do IFS= LC_ALL=C read -rn $i output <MWE.txt ;printf -v _ '%s%n' "$output" slen;echo $slen ${#output} $output;done

Then, If you liked 1st sample, try this other: for i in {3..9};do IFS= LC_ALL=C read -rn $i output <MWE.txt ;printf -v _ '%s%n' "$output" slen;echo $slen ${#output} ${output}$'\260';done which would show non-printable on each lines but lne 6, where you may see degree symbol instead of your middle dot.
